# angular parent component property update does not run methods in child component

Tags: angular

I have the following code in a parent component

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.method().subscribe(r => {
        this.data = r;
    });
}
```

This component is using a child component in the following manner

```
        <childComponent [data]="data">
        </childComponent>
```

Now the child component has the following method

```
ngOnInit(): void {
     if (!this.childProperty) return;

    // do some processing here
}
```

The problem I'm having is that initially when `ngOnInit` is run on the child component there is no data since the `service.method()` has not run on the parent component.  Once the data is back, the child component should run `ngOnInit` again, but how do I do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a condition in template like

```
<childComponent [data]="data" *ngIf="data && data.length > 0">
</childComponent>
```

So, that once the data is available, than only it render the component.

**OR**

Another way is to do, you can implement `ngOnChanges()` instead of `ngOnInit()`, so whenever input property get changes (after the API call) it call that hook and you can do your processing in that hook.